# Copying sheet from one workbook to another workbook formula are not recalculating

Tags: excel, vba

I checked the previous similar posts but couldnt find an answer for my issue.

I have an Excel file A where the code consist of :

- Ask a user to choose a file B via OpenDialogBox  -ok
- Copy a sheet from file A to file B  -ok

The problem is that all formulas display  '#VALUE!"  and I need to double-click on each of the cells to get the result.

I tried this

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

and I even tried directly via Excel Calculate Now in Formula Tab.

It doesnt work.

Comment: Hard to help when there is no code, formula or sample data. Try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64630333/edit) your question to add those specifics.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I have used in the past:

1. replace “=“ with xyxy
2. copy all cells or move / duplicate sheet to new workbook
3. replace xyxy with “=“

This allows all the formulae to be transferred as text and then when the xyxy to = replacement is done all the formulae get recalculated anyway.